# Curl does not redirect

Tags: php, curl

Why is not my curl code redirecting? The url has a redirect on a secure site, but is this the problem? What is wrong?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_all);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ssoportais2.tokiomarine.com.br/openam/XUI/#login/&realm=TOKIOLFR&goto=https://portalparceiros.tokiomarine.com.br/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $retorno = curl_exec($ch);

    if($retorno===false){
        echo '<br>erro:'.curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($retorno);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like redirect is performed using Javascript code. Brief analysis of this page's XHR requests show that it requires some kind of authentication.